# VBA PivotItems Index Variable

Tags: vba, variables, indexing, pivot-table

I am trying to loop through different years of data from a OLAP pivot table and for each year I have to drilldown to get the data I am looking for. Here is what the macro recorder gave me for 2013:

```
'This is the cell that has to be drilled down
Range("A2").Select

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Date].[YMD].[Year Name]") _

.PivotItems("[Date].[YMD].[Year Name].&[***2013***]").DrilledDown = True

End With
```

[Date].[YMD] is the field name and [Year Name] is the source name.

However I am trying to replace the &[2013] with a variable "Yr" which will allow me to select and then drill down into each year.

But I get the following message: "Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class"

Is there a specific syntax for PivotItems Index? Are there limitations to using a variable to reference from an OLAP Pivot Table? I have tried defining Yr as a Double and also as a Variable but it didn't help..

Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: Why do you have an extra "_" in there? That basically is a "continue this command on the next line" syntax in VBA - try your code with it removed. Right now your with doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim YR As Integer

YR = 2013

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Date].[YMD].[Year Name]") _
.PivotItems("[Date].[YMD].[Year Name].&[" & YR & "]").DrilledDown = True


End With
```